# Simple moving average (partial window) of a vector using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a simple vector as follows:

```
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)
```

I am trying to find the rolling mean of this vector and using the following function:

```
library(data.table)
y = frollmean(x, 5)
```

I am getting the result as follows -

```
 [1]     NA     NA     NA     NA 13.334 13.086 13.150 13.856 15.400 16.340
```

However, I want the result as -

```
 [1]     14.24 14.03 13.06 13.43 13.334 13.086 13.150 13.856 15.400 16.340
```

1. The first value should be the same as in the original vector
2. The second value should be the mean of the first and second value
3. The third value should be the mean of the initial three values in the
   vector
4. The fourth value should be the mean of the initial four values in the vector

The rest of the calculation is correctly handled by the function `frollmean`

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo`'s `rollapplyr` function with `partial = TRUE`.

```
zoo::rollapplyr(x, 5, mean, partial = TRUE)
#[1] 14.24 14.03 13.60 13.43 13.33 13.09 13.15 13.86 15.40 16.34
```

Comment: I tried to run the same on the EMA function of TTR library, but it is giving an error. ```zoo::rollapplyr(x, 5, EMA, partial = TRUE)``` Do you know how to fix it? I think EMA function already have rolling window but it does not have any option for setting partial as in ```zoo::rollapplyr```

Comment: I haven't used `EMA` function but yes it has it's own window length. So I think you should not use it in `rollapplyr` function.

Comment: As a follow-up question, I have posted a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597909/exponential-moving-average-of-a-vector-in-r

Answer (score 3):

In your `frollmean` function call you are asking for window of width 5. All of leading elements which are NA could not be computed for this window width because there are not enough elements. Partial window support is presented in [`?frollmean`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/froll.html) manual examples. Below is code adapted from examples to your case.

```r
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)
library(data.table)
an = function(n, len) c(seq.int(n), rep(n, len-n))
y = frollmean(x, an(5, length(x)), adaptive=TRUE)
y
# [1] 14.24000 14.03000 13.60333 13.43250 13.33400 13.08600 13.15000 13.85600 15.40000 16.34000
```

Argument `adaptive` is much more generic (than just logical `partial`) way to customize window width. Here we use helper function `an` to calculate adaptive length of window. If you call just `an` you can observe that window width is now exactly how you expected it to be, rather than 5:

```r
an(5, length(x))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with subgroups in data.tables?

Comment: @Laurence_jj ask new question

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your **~/.Rprofile** if you want to include the functionality in your `base R` arsenal:

```
rollmean <- function(vec, len, prtl = FALSE) {
  if (len > length(vec)) {
    stop(paste("Choose lower range,", len, ">", length(vec)))
  }
  else {
    if (prtl == T) {
      sapply(1:length(vec), function(i) {
        if (i <= len) {
          mean(vec[1:i])
        }
        else {
          mean(vec[(i - (len - 1)):i])
        }
      })
    }
    else {
      sapply(1:length(vec), function(i) {
        if (i - (len - 1) > 0) {
          mean(vec[(i - (len - 1)):i])
        }
        else {
          NA
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

x <- c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)

rollmean( x, 5 )
#[1]     NA     NA     NA     NA 13.334 13.086 13.150 13.856 15.400 16.340

rollmean( x, 5, T )
#[1] 14.24000 14.03000 13.60333 13.43250 13.33400 13.08600 13.15000 13.85600
#[9] 15.40000 16.34000
```