# Exponential moving average of just the last value of a vector in R

Tags: r, ttr

I have a simple vector as follows:

```
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)
```

I have found the EMA of this vector using

```
library(TTR)
y = EMA(x, 5)
```

and the result is

```
[1] NA NA NA NA 13.33400 13.22267 13.52844 14.44563 16.51042 16.88695
```

The next day a new value is added to the end of original vector `x` and the updated `x` vector is:

```
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64, 18.09)
```

The expected output is -

```
y = [1] NA NA NA NA 13.33400 13.22267 13.52844 14.44563 16.51042 16.88695 17.28796
```

This output can be produced by `EMA(x, 5)`, but this statement will calculate EMA of the entire vector again and will be time inefficient.
Since we already have the previous day's EMA calculation in vector `y`,
is there a way to calculate the EMA of just the last 5 days instead of recalculating for the entire vector and merge the new value in vector `y`?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you meant by the last value mean.  There is only single element

Comment: I am still trying to understasnd how you got 18.09 from the `tail(x, 5)`

Comment: The 18.09 calculation is not clear.  I am not getting that value

Comment: Can you show your expected output as it is not clear to me

Comment: I checked your update, but it is still the same input 'x' with `18.09`.  Not clear what your expected output is

Comment: If you want to do this only once, wouldn't it be better to calculate EMA at the end of trial

Comment: What I meant is you don't have to calculate EMA thousand times each day.  Calculate it at the end of a day when the 'x' is nolonger updated

Comment: The ema is calculated with a weight.  `The exponential moving average is a weighted moving average that reduces influences by applying more weight to recent data points () reduction factor`

Comment: If you just subset the last 10 elements and do the EMA, it would be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645594/13513328), looking at C code of `TTR` provides a possible solution :

```r
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)

n <- 5
y = TTR::EMA(x,n)

ratio <- 2 / (n+1)

newx <- 18.09
newy <- tail(y,1) * (1 - ratio) + ratio * newx
newy
#> [1] 17.28796

y = c(y,newy)
y
#>  [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA 13.33400 13.22267 13.52844 14.44563
#>  [9] 16.51042 16.88695 17.28796
```

Comment: Thanks! Using ```y[length(y)]``` instead of tail(y,1) made it considerably faster.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and as usual with R, benchmarking is the only way to find out which solution is faster!

Answer (score 1):

If you read `?TTR::EMA`,

> For 'EMA', 'wilder=FALSE' (the default) uses an exponential smoothing ratio of '2/(n+1)'

It helps to understand that in EMA, this ratio is effectively the weight applied to the current *value* (`x`), and the inverse (one minus this) is applied to the previous *average* (`y`).

```r
x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)
n <- 5
y <- TTR::EMA(x, n)

x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64, 18.09)
ratio <- 2/(n+1)
ratio
# [1] 0.3333333
sum( c(y[10], x[11]) * c(1-ratio, ratio) )
# [1] 17.28796
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the EMA in simple terms. It made my understanding of EMA much clearer.