Error when creating exponential moving average with NA values
I am attempting to create an exponential moving average. However, it seems there isn't a function that handles NA values exactly the same way. So I found a solution from someone that deals with NA values, but not in the way I want:
rollmeanEMA <- function(vec, len) {
  v_n <- !is.na(vec)
  c( vec[is.na(vec)],
     cumsum(vec[v_n][1:(len-1)]) / seq_along(vec[v_n][1:(len-1)]),
     EMA(vec[v_n], len)[len:length(vec[v_n])])
}

When I have NA at the beginning of the vector, it works fine:
dados <- c(NA, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)
> rollmeanEMA(dados, 8)
 [1]        NA 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
 [5] 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4285714
 [9] 0.3750000 0.5781250 0.5058594 0.4426270


but when I have NA in another position, it behaves incorrectly because it moves the NA to the beginning of the vector, and I want it to remain where it is:
dados <- c(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, NA)
> rollmeanEMA(dados, 8)
 [1]        NA 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [5] 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4285714
 [9] 0.3750000 0.3281250 0.5371094 0.4699707```

So, I actually wanted the code to do exactly the same as in a regular moving average and to ignore the NA values. That is, if the data is c(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 2, 0, 4), on the line with NA, I want it to calculate the exponential moving average of c(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0).
If it's on the line with 4, I want it to calculate the exponential average of c(4, 0, 2, 0), ignoring c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 3), thus using 8 values from the time window.
It's worth noting that I'm working with a dynamic time window, so if there aren't 7 previous data points before the line where I want to calculate the average, the ma_len (moving average length) will be the number of lines that exist before it, i.e., ma_len = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, ...) for each group.

Then change c( vec[is.na(vec)],, this puts NAs to the front.

Does not work with non leading NA's

source of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597909/exponential-moving-average-of-a-vector-in-r I do not understand the explanation.

Only works with leading NA's. If you run x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, NA, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64) it returns an error:Error in TTR::EMA(x, n) : Series contains non-leading NAs

Change your methode or use an NA-approximation technique, e.g., EMA(zoo::na.approx(x), 8)or EMA2(zoo::na.approx(x), 8). Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/582

I want to ignore the NA values and maintain the structure of the data, that is, the size of the data table. I want to calculate the exponential moving average of sales with a time window of 8 weeks, but if there are no sales in one of the weeks

I don't want to assign values to that NA because it will drastically alter the average. So if I have (14.24, 13.82, 12.75, NA, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64), the moving average at the line of 16.28 must be the average of (14.24, 13.82, 12.75, , 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28), the blank space represents the ignored NA, so the average will only have 7 values. If I were to insert 0, it would significantly alter my average. The only way to not alter the average would be to replace the NA with the average value, but I'm not sure if there are techniques to do that.

Too long for a comment.
From what I understand you would like to select eight (past) values of x per iteration and calculate an exponentially weighted (moving) average (~EMA) of those.
If the selected sequence contains NA values, you would like to ignore those and reduce n (= "Number of periods to average over. [...]", cp. ?TTR::EMA) dynamically to match the length of non-NA values in the selected window.
You might try a variant of
unrecommended = \(x, k) {
  # I use k instead of n
  y = rep(NA, length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) 
    if (i > k) { 
      rw = na.omit(x[(i-k+1L):i]); l = length(rw)
      if(k >= l) y[[i]] = TTR::EMA(rw, k)[[k]] else y[[i]] = TTR::EMA(rw, l)[[l]] 
    }
  y
}

which gives for k = 2, 4, 6, 8
> x = c(14.24, 13.82, 12.75, 12.92, 12.94, 13.00, 14.14, 16.28, 20.64, 17.64)
> lapply(c(2,4,6,8), \(k) unrecommended(x, k = k))
[[1]]
 [1]     NA     NA 13.285 12.835 12.930 12.970 13.570 15.210
 [9] 18.460 19.140

[[2]]
 [1]      NA      NA      NA      NA 13.1075 12.9025 13.2500
 [8] 14.0900 16.0150 17.1750

[[3]]
 [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [7] 13.26167 13.67167 14.98667 15.77333

[[4]]
 [1]       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
 [7]       NA       NA 14.56125 15.03875

Obviously, this approach is right-aligned, you might replace leading NAs (naturally occuring due to i < k) with an idea similar to @Waldi's EMA2().
I think the approach behind unrecommended() is wrong. I suggest to change the approach. Please study

How to handle 'Series contains non-leading NAs' in TTR library with xts objects?
https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/582
perhaps zoo::na.locf(), see Change NAs to interpolated flat bars

Note

Source of the code you show: Exponential moving average of a vector in R
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44650/a-simpler-way-to-calculate-exponentially-weighted-moving-average
https://mathematical-modeling-python.blogspot.com/2013/11/exponentially-weighted-moving-average.html


What is important here is to clarify the rules.  We assume
these rules at each iteration:

Take the most recent 8 values or however many exist if fewer than 8 exist.
If all entries of that are NA return NA.
trim NAs off ends and insert an NA before what remains
From what remains take everything after the last NA.
Take exponential average of what is left.

Code
library(TTR)
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) {
  if(all(is.na(x))) return(NA)
  x <- c(NA, na.trim(x))
  wx <- which(is.na(x))
  x <- tail(x,-max(wx))
  tail(EMA(x,length(x)), 1)
}

x <- c(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 2, 0, 4)
rollapplyr(x, 8, roll, partial = TRUE)
##  [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4285714
##  [8] 0.4285714 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 1.5000000

